# How to replace dryRun flag in Google Content API for Shopping v2.1

Tags: google-content-api

The dryRun mode flag in google content api v2 is extremely useful and it's going to be hard to live without in forth coming v2.1. Can someone suggest useful strategies to compensate?

Thanks